# Infinite-dimensional optimal control problem with a continuum of state equations

Tags: functional-analysis, control-theory, optimal-control

I have the following problem

$$
\max_{[I_i]_{i=0}^{\infty}} \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\eta}\left(A_i(t) h_i(t) - I_i(t)^q  \right) di dt
$$
subjected to
$$
\dot{h}_i(t) = I_i(t) - \delta h_i(t) \hspace{2mm}\forall i \in [0,\eta]
$$
where $q >1$ and $\delta \in (0,1)$ and where $A_i >0$ and $\eta >0$.

I'm trying to figure out what are the necessary conditions of this problem, but I don't know the derivation of those conditions.

Comment: Are there any assumptions regarding $h_i(0)$?

Comment: $h_i(0)$ must be positive.